# Duplicate record stored in Preference after Pull Referesh on Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-volley, pull-to-refresh

I am using `PullToRefresh` for `RecyclerView`.Everytime when new data is displayed on Recyclerview it is stored in `SharedPreference`.If Internet connectivity is gone  I am showing data on `RecyclerView` from `SharedPreference`.When PullToRefresh is done multiple times the same data from Recyclerview is stored in Preference.And when Internet Connectivity is gone and data is fetched from Preference it is showing duplicate records in Recyclerview.How to avoid this ?
This is code for `PullToRefresh`

```
pullRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        current.clear();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pullRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        checkInternet();
                    }
                }, 1000);  
            }
        });
```

This is code for `checkInternet`.If internet available bring latest data from webservice and store in Preferene otherwise bring data from Preference

```
public void checkInternet(){
       String NetworkStatus = biz.fyra.bookapp.utils.NetworkStatus.checkConnection(getContext());
       if (NetworkStatus.equals("false")) {
           current.clear();
           String 1stJSON = firstStatus.getString("firstList", "");
           String 2ndJSON = secondData.getString("secondListList", "");
           if (!1stJSON.equals("") && !2ndJSON.equals("")) {
               try {
                   readCachedData(1stJSON, 2ndJSON);
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
          snackbar=Snackbar.make(recyclerView,"You are Offline.",
                  Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
             checkInternet();
              }
          });
          snackbar.show();
       }else{
           current.clear();
           getData();
       } 
   }
```

`getData` is actual WebService call.How to resolve this ?

Comment: what is in readCachedData

Comment: what are you storing in sharedPreference? share that code

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Just add this line:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in the below mentioned (Write here):

```
public void checkInternet(){
     String NetworkStatus = biz.fyra.bookapp.utils.NetworkStatus.checkConnection(getContext());
     if (NetworkStatus.equals("false")) {
       current.clear();
       ........... (Write here)
       String 1stJSON = firstStatus.getString("firstList", "");
       String 2ndJSON = secondData.getString("secondListList", "");
       ......
       ......
```

Try it.

One more thing,

```
pullRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    current.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    pullRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                    checkInternet();
                }
            }, 1000);  
        }
    });
```

In the above code remove any one of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

No need to add it twice.